# How to dynamically change a function interface, e.g. f() -> f(a, b, c='default')

Tags: python

I would like to dynamically create methods in a class B that have the same name and 'interface' (with that I mean args/kwargs/defaults list) as the methods in class A, but different code.

Generic interfaces like f(*args, **kwargs) are not desirable.

Generating the methods and adding them dynamically with something like    setattr(self.__class__, fa.__name__, fb), copying docstrings, etc., is easy enough. But I found no way of copying the 'interface' dynamically. Write access to fb.__code__.co_argcount /.co_varnames does not work.

The closest solution I found was dynamically creating the methods in a string and then attaching them to the class, like:

```
code = '''def f(a,b): ...'''  
ns = {}  
exec code in ns  
setattr(self.__class__, 'f', ns['f'])
```

But I do not like that approach and would much prefer generating my methods from a generic method by dynamically changing its interface. (Inspecting and using that interface from within the method is not an issue.)

Any way to do that?

(Use case: The methods in class B 'call' their 'mirror'-methods in class A, which run in a different process, via zeroMQ messaging and then return the results, providing a local 'mirror'-interface. As there may be a large number of different 'remote' classes A1..An, I do not want to have to create and maintain all the corresponding classes B1..Bn manually, but to have one generic class B, which will adapt itself automatically to any class Ax passed to it.)

My first post, hope that is reasonably clear...
THX!

Comment: How do you intend to dynamically generate the actual function body?  You'll have to use `compile` or something to do that anyway, so why not use it to define the signature too?

Comment: I was hoping to be able to: (1) declare a generic function, which inspects and processes its own signature, and then (2) create copies of it and modify their names and signatures to match those in class A

Comment: ... could also create them like this: 
`def makeFn(cls, fnName, **signatureInfo):
    def newFn(self):
        # Generic code acting based on self-inspection and/or 
**signatureInfo  
   setattr(cls, fnName, newFn)`  
but that still leaves me with the problme of changing the signature of the new function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify a function's signature once it's created.  You'll have to do as you describe.  The source of the [`decorator`](https://github.com/micheles/decorator/blob/master/src/decorator.py) library may be useful to you, as it contains a mechanism for making a function with a given signature.

Comment: That should do. THX!